# during accessing vector, resizing it can cause a crash?

Tags: vector, thread-safety, resize, allocation

```
typedef std::vector<int> testVec;

void threadA()
{
   testVec[0] = 1;
}

void threadB()
{
   testVec.resize(10);
}
```

like above psuedo code, while accessing vector by thread A, if thread b tries to resize vector at the same time, it can cause crash??
how about opposite case??

while resizing vector by thread b, thread a tries to update value to vector.
it also cause crash??

Thanks in advance.

I guess it can be crash,as far as i know, resize means reallocation.